# Changing database links has no effect

Tags: database, css

So I just moved my website from localhost (127.0.0.1/wordpress) to a server. I followed many tutorials and I managed to get the site going. The home page loads, the content is there, however, subpages and css don't work/load. (the home page is blank, without any css applied).

Apparently, the problem is in MySQL database. I tried multiple times to replace 127.0.0.1/wordpress with mydomain.com, but nothing seems to be working. No matter what I change those values to, all the links are mydomain.com/wordpress.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Did you changed the homepage url and wordpress url in database?

Comment: Exactly what links are you talking about? Do you have the local address hard coded into any files?

Comment: Yes I've changed that.

Essentially every link on a webpage. What I did recently is that I created a wordpress dir on FTP server and move stuff there, but now people would have to input mydomain.com/wordpress to access my webpage, which is clearly not the way I want it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't tell exactly what you are asking but this comment...

> What I did recently is that I created a wordpress dir on FTP server
>   and move stuff there, but now people would have to input
>   mydomain.com/wordpress to access my webpage...

... makes me wonder it you don't have a subdirectory install. If that is the case, you need to [follow the instructions in the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory#Using_a_pre-existing_subdirectory_install) to get this working.

> 1. Go to the General panel.
> 2. In the box for **Site address (URL):** change the address
>      to the root directory's URL. Example: http://example.com
> 3. Click **Save Changes**. (Do not worry about the error
>      message and do not try to see your blog at this point! You will
>      probably get a message about file not found.)
> 4. Copy (NOT
>      MOVE!) the index.php and .htaccess files from the
>      WordPress  (wordpress in our example) directory into the root
>      directory of your site—the latter is probably named something like
>      www or public_html. The .htaccess file is
>      invisible, so you may have to set your FTP client to show hidden files. If you are
>      not using pretty permalinks, then you may not have
>      a .htaccess file. ***If you are running WordPress on a
>      Windows (IIS) server** and are using pretty permalinks, you'll have
>      a web.config rather than a .htaccess file in your
>      WordPress directory.*
> 5. Edit your root directory's
>      index.php.
>
>    1. Open your root directory's
>         index.php file in a text editor
>    2. Change the line that
>         says:
>       require('./wp-blog-header.php');
>       to the
>         following, using your directory name for the WordPress core
>         files:
>       require('./wordpress/wp-blog-header.php');
>    3. Save the file.
> 6. Login to your site (if
>      you aren't still already). The URL should still be
>      http://example.com/wordpress/wp-admin/
> 7. If you have
>      set up [Permalinks](/Using_Permalinks), go to the Permalinks panel and update your Permalink
>      structure. WordPress will automatically update your .htaccess
>      file if it has the appropriate file permissions. If WordPress can't
>      write to your .htaccess file, it will display the new rewrite
>      rules to you, which you should manually copy into your
>      .htaccess file (in the same directory as the main
>      index.php file.)

Comment: I can't change the Site adress in the box. It's shaded.

Comment: Then the Site address is probably hard-coded into the `wp-config.php` file: http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#WordPress_address_.28URL.29

Comment: Yeah. Changed it there and it works! Sorry for a late reply.